# Latex Alignment Problem

Tags: fancyhdr, watermark

How can I make the straight line in the middle come right in the middle and the numbers are aligned right and left exactly?

```
\documentclass[10 pt]{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,total={7.6in,9.2in}]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Example}
\lhead{Questions}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents=EXAMPLE, opacity=0.3, scale=6, color=gray, angle=45, vshift=0.5cm, hshift=0.2cm}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{
  \shortstack{
         \\[5em]  Example. 
  }}
\SetWatermarkScale{0.7}
\SetWatermarkColor[gray]{0.85}
\begin{document} 
\raggedbottom
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
\item[\textbf{1.}].\\
            
            \textbf{Answer.}\\[80mm]
            
    
            
            
            
\item[\textbf{2.}].\\
            
            \textbf{Answer.}          
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}%
    \vrule
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth}
    \begin{enumerate}
    
    
    
\item[\textbf{3.}].\\
            
            \textbf{Answer.}\\[80mm]




\item[\textbf{4.}].\\
            
\textbf{Answer.}
    
    \end{enumerate} 
\end{minipage}% 



\end{document}
```

Comment: The straight line in the middle is "right in the middle". The watermark isn't.  Maybe you should consider rephrasing your question in a more meaningful and elaborative way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put the vertical rule in the horizontal center of the text area:

(1) Suppress the indent and

(2) Use `\hfill\vrule\hfill` to keep the rule centered, independently of the minipages widths (both the same).

Added `showframe` to display the margins.

To suppress the indent in the enumerate environment load the package `enumitem` and use     `\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]`

[image: x]

```
\documentclass[10 pt]{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,total={7.6in,9.2in}]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{showframe} % added to diplay de margin<<<<< 
\usepackage{enumitem}% added <<<<<

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Example}
\lhead{Questions}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents=123456789X123456789, opacity=0.3, scale=5.7, color=gray, angle=0, vshift=1.0cm, hshift=0.0cm} % changed for testing

\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{
    \shortstack{
        \\[5em]  Example. 
}}
\SetWatermarkScale{0.7}
\SetWatermarkColor[gray]{0.85}

\begin{document} 
    \raggedbottom
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth} % changed
        \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
            \item[\textbf{1.}]           
            \textbf{Answer.}\\[80mm]            
            \item[\textbf{2.}]
            \textbf{Answer.} 
        \end{enumerate}        
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill\vrule\hfill % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth} % changed 
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
    \item[\textbf{1.}]           
    \textbf{Answer.}\\[80mm]            
    \item[\textbf{2.}]
    \textbf{Answer.} 
\end{enumerate}        
\end{minipage}% 

\end{document}
```